# ORA-00922: missing or invalid option | SQL*PLUS commands using OracleClient

Tags: c#, oracle, ado.net, oracleclient

```
    OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection();
    conn.ConnectionString = @"Data Source=(DESCRIPTION =(ADDRESS_LIST =(ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 10.206.0.23)(PORT = 1521)))(CONNECT_DATA = (SID = ORCLWEX3)));User Id= RAMNIVAS_CI;Password= RAMNIVAS_CI;";
    conn.Open();


    SetStatus(null, "CLEARING CI DATABASE");
    OracleCommand com = new OracleCommand(@"set pages 0
                    set lines 80
                    spool c:\delete_objects_CI
                    select 'drop '||object_type||' '||object_name||';'
                    from user_objects;
                    spool off
                    start c:\delete_objects_CI.lst
                    purge recyclebin;
                    set pages 100", conn);
    com.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

I guess there is some problem in the query I am trying to execute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot execute SQL*plus commands with the Oracle client. SQL*plus commands are only supported by SQL*plus and some Oracle tools like SQL Developer.

Your code basically iterates over all objects of the current user and then drops them. You should be able to achieve the same with a loop:

```
OracleCommand userObjCmd = new OracleCommand("select object_type, object_name from user_objects", conn);
OracleDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
while (reader.Read())
{
    OracleCommand dropCmd = new OracleCommand(
        String.Format(@"execute immedidate 'drop {0} \"{1}\"'",
            reader.GetValue(0), reader.GetValue(1)),
        conn);
    dropCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

You will need to add some code for properly closing the command and reader instances and for handling errors.

And you might need to discard errors silently and try to repeat the above code several times until all objects have been successfully dropped since some objects cannot drop as long as other objects depend on it.

Comment: Thanks, even if I use your method for deleting objects, the problem is that I have to restore that DB(we have DMP and text file for it) and also take backup using SQL PLUS. Is there any way to do that ?

Comment: Is the DMP file from the *exp* or *expdp* utility? And what sort of text file do you have for restoring the DB? And how do you want to backup the DB with SQL*plus? Whatever, the best approach is to run SQL*plus, imp, impdb etc. in a separate process.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to execute SQL*Plus commands through your driver. I do not think this can be done.

Comment: So is there any way to accomplish the same using my driver ? I think the above script just clears up everything from the specified database.

Comment: Best way is to drop the user and recreate it. Above method errors out when parent tables are dropped before child tables, when indexes are dropped and they are not there because the table is dropped, etc.. Another way is to write a stored procedure that clears up everything and call it from your code.

Comment: I dont think we have the authority to drop user and recreate it. Can you let me know any other method ?